# Menu in html and css doesn't work well

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu in css and html. i don't know which size i'm going to use eventually so I did a menu that can be whatever size horizontally and vertically I want it to be but I have one issue. The right side of the menu is hidden for some reason.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<table>
        <tr>
                <td id="menu_top_left"></td><td id="menu_top_center"></td><td id="menu_top_right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 5</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="menu_center">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Link 6</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td id="menu_bot_left"></td><td id="menu_bot_center"></td><td id="menu_bot_right"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
        width:200px;
        border-spacing:0;
}
table tr #menu_top_left{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(top_left.png);
}
table tr #menu_top_center{
        width:160px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(top_center.png) repeat-x;
}
table tr #menu_top_right{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(top_right.png) repeat-x;
}
table #menu_center{
        background:url(center_center.png) repeat;
        text-align:center;
}
table tr #menu_bot_left{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(bot_left.png);
}
table tr #menu_bot_center{
        width:160px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(bot_center.png) repeat-x;
}
table tr #menu_bot_right{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:url(bot_right.png) repeat-x;
}
```

The right part which hidden supposed to be just like the left part which not hidden. I cant find a way to fix it.
hope someone could fix it for me, thanks.
Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: You really should provide more detailed info with some code-shots instead of just "go to my code and fix it for me".

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't be using tables for formatting; they're used for displaying tabular data. Your navigation links are actually just items on a list, so use the < ul > and < li > tags instead. You can contain these elements inside of a  tag.

Secondly, you're using images, when you really don't need to. You want to achieve:

- A red single pixel border
- Rounded corners
- A red 'glow' around the container.

You can get all three of these effects using the following CSS attributes:

- [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)
- [border-radius](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)
- [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

Edit: Here's an example in action. You'll see how much easier it is this way :)

http://jsfiddle.net/ntwiles/9Qv3h/

```
d
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Nathan's suggestions above, but in the interest of helping you learn what's wrong with your current code:

You have an uneven number of cells in your table - three in the top and bottom rows, and only two in the center. You'll need to increase your colspans to "3" so that your cells span the whole width of the row. Additionally, I would apply the background styling at the td level rather than the tr level, as you've done with top and bottom.